Do three points of inequality between convex functions imply inequality over an interval?
Say I have 2 convex functions, $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. I want to prove that $f(x) > g(x), \forall x \in [l, u]$.
I know that $f(l) > g(l)$ and $f(u) > g(u)$. I evaluate the functions at a third point $l < x_0 < u$, and find that here too $f(x_0) > g(x_0)$. Does this necessarily mean that $f(x) > g(x), \forall x \in [l, u]$?
I cannot find a counterexample, but I also do not know how to prove this property.

Let $f(x)=x^2,g(x)=x^4+1/5$. Both are convex functions.
We have $f(4/5)>g(4/5)$, $f(3/5)>g(3/5)$ and $f(-3/5)>g(-3/5)$ but $f(0)<g(0)$.

Sorry for any confusion. You've shown that if $f$ > $g$ at the end points of an interval, the functions can still intersect within that interval. My question is if I also have a third point, $x_3$ for which $f(x_3) > g(x_3)$, can there be a fourth point where $f(x_4) < g(x_4)$.

I fixed the error.
